# Mapping a deeply-nested property_path to a parent form

Tags: forms, symfony

I'm building a form in Symfony 2 whose fields will vary depending on how the corresponding entity is configured.

Briefly, each entity has a set of "detail" fields that can hold different types and configurations of data.

For example, a `Project` entity might have the following configuration:

- `url` renders as a text input and validates as a URL with max length of 300 chars.
- `description` renders as a textarea with no validation constraints.
- `logo` renders as a file input and validates as an image file with max dimensions of 500x500.

And so on.  The part that makes this interesting is that all of this is configured via database tables so that an administrator could change the configuration of these models via a UI.

The (relevant part of the) database structure looks something like this:

[image: ERD showing 4 tables - project, project_detail, detail_type and detail_type_assignment]

- `project` stores the Project records.
- `project_detail` stores the value of each detail field for each Project.
- `detail_type` defines the type and configuration for each detail field.
- `detail_type_assignment` defines which detail types are available for each entity and the order in which the fields should display on forms.

Everything is working great so far except for rendering error messages in forms.

When any of these detail fields generates a validation error, it is displayed at the top of the form:

[image: Screenshot of project edit form with detail field error messages displayed at the top.]

Note in the above image, "EIN" is a field that exists in the `Project` entity (i.e., implemented the normal way for a Symfony form), while "URL" and "Logo Upload" are implemented as detail fields.

Here's what the `ProjectType` looks like:

```
class ProjectType extends AbstractType
{
    public function buildForm(FormBuilderInterface $builder, array $options)
    {
        $builder
            ->add('name')
            ->add('ein', 'ein')
        ;

        /* Add detail fields to the form builder. */
        foreach($this->getDetailTypes() as $detailType)
        {
            $slug       = $detailType->getSlug();
            $formatter  = $detailType->createFormatterInstance('');

            $builder->add(
                  $slug
                , $formatter->getFormFieldType()
                , $formatter->getFormFieldOptions()
            );

            /* E.g.,
             *
             * $builder->add(
             *     'url'
             *   , 'text'
             *   , array('label' => 'URL', ...)
             * )
             */
        }
    }

    ...
}
```

I'm pretty sure what's going on here is that the `ViolationMapper` can't translate the `property_path` correctly.

For example, at runtime, the `property_path` of the `url` value is `project.details[url].value`, but the field is located at `project.url`.

I would prefer not to construct a complex form hierarchy so that the position of each field matches its `property_path`.  Is there a way I can change path that violations get added to in the `ExecutionContext`?

Comment: Could you post twig code also?

Answer (score 0):

In your view I feel like you shouldn't use `form(form)` inside of  `form_start(form)` and `form_end(form)`. I believe that would generate the `<form>` tag twice

**Old answer:**

Idk what your twig looks like but I'm assuming somehow the error in the form row isn't being displayed. http://symfony.com/doc/current/book/forms.html#rendering-a-form-in-a-template talks about it.

From the link:

```
{# src/Acme/TaskBundle/Resources/views/Default/new.html.twig #}
{{ form_start(form) }}
{{ form_errors(form) }}

{{ form_row(form.task) }}
{{ form_row(form.dueDate) }}
{{ form_end(form) }}

Take a look at each part:
form_start(form) - Renders the start tag of the form.
form_errors(form) - Renders any errors global to the whole form (field-specific errors are displayed next to each field);
form_row(form.dueDate) - Renders the label, any errors, and the HTML form widget for the given field (e.g. dueDate) inside, by default, a div element;
form_end() - Renders the end tag of the form and any fields that have not yet been rendered. This is useful for rendering hidden fields and taking advantage of the automatic CSRF Protection.
```

form_row can be split into each of its parts:

```
<div>
    {{ form_label(form.task) }}
    {{ form_errors(form.task) }}
    {{ form_widget(form.task) }}
</div>
```

and the form_errors() function should display what you want.

Comment: Hi Ozzie.  Thanks for the suggestions.  However, the issue is not that the errors are being rendered in the wrong place.  The issue is that the error messages are being associated with the root form rather than the field they apply to (e.g., the error for the URL field is rendered in `form_errors(form)`, while `form_errors(form.url)` does not render any errors).